# Assume $f(x)$ is integrable in $[a,b]$, $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text dx=0 $

Tags: calculus

Assume $f(x)$ is integrable in $[a,b]$, $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text dx=0 $,  $\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\text dt \ge0 $.
Prove $$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x) \text dx\le 0 $$
Trying to connect with MVT of integral... having no more clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just integrate the inequality $\int_a ^{x} f(t)\, dt \geq 0$ from $a$ to $b$. You get $\int_a^{b} \int_a ^{x} f(t)\, dt \, dx\geq 0$. Interchanging the integrals this becomes $\int_a^{b} \int_t ^{b} f(t) \, dx \, dt\geq 0$. This gives $\int_a^{b} (b-t) f(t)  dt\geq 0$. Hence $b\int_a^{b} f(t)  dt -\int_a^{b} tf(t)  dt \geq 0$. Since the first term is $0$ we get $\int_a^{b} tf(t)  dt \leq 0$.